# Who was the original owner of Orcrist?

Tags: the-hobbit, tolkiens-legendarium, elves, the-silmarillion

We know that Glamdring and Orcrist are both from Gondolin, and that Glamdring belonged to Turgon. All I found about Orcrist is a line from the Hobbit saying that it belonged to some great hero of the Gondolindrim. Does anybody know who that hero might be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Tolkien never wrote anything on the matter, so speculation is all you'll get.  There's some discussion here: http://lotr.wikia.com/wiki/Orcrist with a conclusion that the original owner may have been Ecthelion (and the rather neat observation that this would mean that Orcrist was also used to slay a Balrog).

Comment: ...although the intention seems to be that Ecthelion was to still kill Gothmog with the spike on his helmet, which Tolkien explicitly mentions when describing his armour in *Of Tuor...* - "upon his shining helm there was set a spike of steel pointed with a diamond" - a Chekhov's Spike indeed!